ChromaDB terminates Flask without exception
I'm creating an API with Flask. The other side will send me a file and I will save it to chroma database on my side. Chroma.add will terminates my program without any exception. When I save a smaller file to it, it will be fine, when send a larger file it will crash. Firstly, I thought it might be memory problem, and I tested the same code in jupyter notebook outside flask. When I run the same code in jupyter notebook, it will run properly. I tried many ways to test it. For example I put it into the try except structure but the print in except is never caught.
The program runs until Chroma.add and then crashes.
def save_w_chunking(self, docs: List[Document]) -> None:

    text_splitter = SemanticChunker(self._embeddings, breakpoint_threshold_type = "percentile", breakpoint_threshold_amount = 80, sentence_split_regex = r'(?<=[。？！])|(?<=\n)')

    docs = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)

    seen_docs = []
    temp_docs = []
        
    for d in docs:

        is_unique = d.page_content not in seen_docs
        has_content = len(d.page_content.strip().strip("\n")) > 0

        if is_unique and has_content:

            seen_docs.append(d.page_content)

            d.page_content =  d.metadata["filename"] + ":\n" + d.page_content

            temp_docs.append(d)

    docs = temp_docs
    docs = filter_complex_metadata(docs)

    if len(docs) == 0:
        return
    
    try:

        t = [d.page_content for d in docs]
        m = [d.metadata for d in docs]
        ids = [str(uuid.uuid4()) for _ in range(len(t))]

        self._ChromaDB.add(ids = ids,
                           documents = t,
                           metadatas = m)

    except Exception as e:
        print("caught exception: ", e)

Here's the implementation of flask.
@app.route('/ChromaEditor', methods = ['POST'])
def upload_file():
    result = {"msg" : "success"}
    file = request.files["file"]
    file_path = os.path.join("blink", file.filename)
    file.save(file_path)          
    text_doc, table_doc = unstrucutured_to_Doc([file_path])          
    print("successfully parsed " + file.filename)          
    CE.save_w_chunking(text_doc)     
    CE.save_wo_chunking(table_doc)          
    print("successfully saved " + file.filename)          
    return result


 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
Press CTRL+C to quit
successfully parsed hello.docx

(llm) C:\Users\Desktop>

I want to fix this, thank you so much
